# MVC Validation: Same project, different languages: why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, localization

When I start my MVC application and try to sumbit a form with an empty field than validation is fired and the following message appears (german):

```
Das Feld "Telefon" ist erforderlich.
```

If i do the same on my bosses computer, the message is

```
The Telefon field is required.
```

I checked if out windows settings for region and language are different, but they are the same? What else could be the reason?

**EDIT**

Solution is to install 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended DEU Language Pack' (or your perferred language) and to add the culture information in Views/web.config in the   `<system.web>`-Part:

```
   <globalization culture="de-DE" uiCulture="de-DE"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your computer you probably installed the German localized version of the .NET Framework so all error messages are coming from the localized satellite assemblies. Phil Haack blogged about [localizing validation messages](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/12/localizing-aspnetmvc-validation.aspx).

Comment: Darin, how could I check, if my version of visual studio is German localized?

Comment: @Simon, it's not Visual Studio, it's the .NET Framework. But assuming you installed the .NET Framework through Visual Studio if your VS is localized chances are the .NET Framework will also be localized.

Comment: I deinstalled "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended DEU Language Pack" and now the english messages are displayed. Tanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

In most browsers you can specify your preferred languages. These can be different from your windows settings.

Comment: I don't think that this is the reason because I get english messages as well when starting the application on our development server.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Accepted-language` request header.

Comment: How can I do that? Do you mean in debug mode in VS?